# What does the Strike attribute do?

Tags: powerstar-golf

Equipping your golfers affects each of their stats: Power, Accuracy, Strike, Spin, and Putting.  Most of them are pretty straightforward, but what does Strike do?

Answer (score 1):

I believe it makes the area under the accuracy meter larger, giving you a smaller chance to hook or slice.